# Visual Studio opening saved project from file

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am relatively new to Visual Studio, but not so bad with programming. Each time I create a project, for example in VB console app mode, I will Save Module x As...

When I come back to open it later and go through File, Open etc, the project opens but not as a working project. In fact, it doesn't really know that it is even a console app file/project. I'm clearly doing something wrong.

Cheers,

Mike

Answer (score 0):

Open the Solution File (.sln) from the Open Project/Solution option, this should open the entire project associated with it.

By the sounds of it, you are opening individual files and therefore it isn't opening all components.

Comment: Thanks for this. But we're still having a couple of issues. We create a VB project in Console Application, name it etc. What is then the protocol for saving??? Clicking on File only give you the Save Project As... .vb and not .sln. I manually type the file extension (.sln) and it looks as though it has saved with the VS logo, but trying to open it results in an error saying that it is an invalid file type.